# calculate the probability of normal distribution variable with conditions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> There're 3 brothers who are saving money every month. The 1st brother saves \$160 monthly; the savings of the 2nd brother obey normal distribution with $E=\$280$ ($E$ = expected value), $\sigma = 30$ ($\sigma$ = standard deviation); the savings of the 3rd brother are 1.5 times bigger than that of the 2nd brother. The monthly savings are independent in different months.
>
> The parents of the brothers decide to add \$100 each month when the 1st and the 2nd brother save more than the 3rd brother. What is the probability that in a given month the parents will add money?

Let "brother" = $B$, then I think I need to calculate $P(B_3<B_2+B_1) = \phi(B_3) - \phi(B_2+B_1)$. But $B_1$ doesn't obey normal distribution, nor we know that $B_3$ does. And even if they did should all variables be equal of its expected value for the calculations?

Comment: third brother is bigger than the second brother probably, not himself

Comment: @Momo all I know is that $E(B_3)>E(B_2)$ but we need to find the probability of the event $P(B_3<B_2+B_1)$ no?

Comment: I'm talking about "the savings of the 3rd brother are 1.5 times bigger than that of the 3nd brother"

Comment: Momo has pointed out a probable typo in the last line of the first paragraph, conjecturing, if my understanding is correct, that '3nd' should be '2nd'.

Comment: that's right but when I calculate the probability how do we know how much borthers saved in a given month? should I just assume they mean expected values?

Comment: There is only one random thing here, which is $B_2$. I already solved it for you in the answers.

Comment: @Jan true it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_1$ is a constant (equals 160 with probability 1)

Now:

$$P(B_1+B_2>B_3)=P(160+B_2>1.5 B_2)=P(0.5 B_2<160)=P(B_2<320)$$

and i think you can solve the rest yourself.

Comment: how can we assume that 3rd brother's savings also obey normal distribution ? They just said that the expected value is 1.5 times bigger than that of the second brother

Comment: and also should I just assume in these types of questions that they assume expected values of variables? because each brother can save unpredictable and different amounts of money each month

Comment: I haven't really used that the third brother's savings obey a normal distribution in the solution, but  the answer is yes. In other words if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $a$ is a constant then $aX\sim N(a\mu,a^2\sigma^2)$. And no, the problem is not about expectations. The problem is about the probability of a normal random variable to take values in a given interval, in your case $(-\infty, 320)$

Comment: so what are the values you plug inside $P()$? I see them as expected values but I don't understand why we need to base our calculation on expected values for this problem because one month 3rd brother can save more money than the other 2 theoretically

Comment: They are random variables, not expected values. It is like rolling a die. Do you get a random variable or an expected value? Think about a similar problem like: you roll a die each month and if face "6" comes up, your parents give to you $100.

Answer (score 1):

From the question, $B_{1}=160$, $B_{2}\sim\mathcal{N}(280,30^2)$ and $B_{3}=1.5B_{2}$. You are looking for $\mathbb{P}[B_{1}+B_{2}\geq B_{3}]=\mathbb{P}[160+B_{2}\geq 1.5B_{2}]=\mathbb{P}[B_{2}\leq320]$. Since $B_{2}\sim\mathcal{N}(280,30^{2})$, $\frac{B_{2}-280}{30}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Hence $\mathcal{P}[B_{2}\leq320]=\mathcal{P}[\frac{B_{2}-280}{30}\leq\frac{4}{3}]=\Phi(\frac{4}{3})\approx0.91$, where $\Phi$ is *cdf* of standard normal distribution.